# Динамический список элементов в NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Подскажите, как сделать в NavigationView динамический список с элементами.
Я пытался сделать через ListView просто разместив ListView в разметке шаблона NavigationView и заполнив его через адаптер, но приложение вылетает с ошибкой:

Стандартный шаблон в NavigationView виджетом внутри NavigationDrawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Пункты меню определяются в файле ресурса меню и закрепляются за NavigationView в строке:

```
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
```

Вот сам файл @menu/activity_main_drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools"/>
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Вместо этих пунктов я пытался создать динамически создаваемый список ListView просто вставив его туда:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <ListView 
android:id = "@+id/listView"
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height = "match_parent"/>

    </menu>
```

И инициализировать через адаптер из onCreate():

```
ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.listView );
        final String[] sets = new String[] {
                "one",
                "two",
                "three",
                "four",
                "five"
        };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this,
                                                                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                                                 sets );
        listView.setAdapter( adapter );
```

Приложение вылетает с ошибкой. Собственно и понятно, что пока NavigationView не открыт, то и ListView не существует и при создании активности инициализировать несуществующий элемент не получится.

Comment: вам нужно поместить ваш ListView прямо в разметку, туда, где у вас сам NavigationDrawer.

Comment: @metalurgus, в стандартном шаблоне с NavigationDrawer который предлагает AndroidStudio, я просто удалил пункты меню по умолчанию и вставил туда ListView. Собственно, как я понимаю, это и есть сама разметка NavigationDrawer. Или есть еще какая-то другая разметка?

Comment: см. ответ. Разметка - это файл вашего `layout`

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Сюда вставьте ваш основной layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- а это ListView, в котором будет меню-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView "
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Дальше просто получаете `ListView` при помощи `findViewById(R.id.listView)`, и работаете с ним, как с обычным `ListView`

Это, как не странно, описано в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). Вам бы следовало сначала заглянуть туда.

Comment: Похоже я немного неправильно задал вопрос, запутался в понятиях. В NavigationDrawer используется виджет NavigationView - вот именно в него мне и нужно поместить динамический список, а не заменить его списком. Извиняюсь, сразу не разобрался.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКузнецов, ну так покажите, что там где используется. А то как-то не понятно, и не очевидно...

Comment: обновил вопрос.